# not able to run webdriverIO scripts with chrome browser version 108

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver-io

My chrome browser got updated to Version 108.0.5359.72
and now while running webdriverIO scripts it gives the below error even after updating the driver: ERROR webdriver: WebDriver Error: Could not start a new session. Error while creating a session with the driver service. Stopping driver service: The driver server process died prematurely.

Also have tried: npm install chromedriver@108 --save-dev

npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for chromedriver@108.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:rIO>

but getting errors.

Answer (score 0):

107.0.3 is the available ChromeDriver version on NPM, that's why you are not able to get 108.

```
npm install --save-dev chromedriver@latest
```

I hope the above should work for you.

Comment: Hi Moeen, Thanks for your response but it still gives the same error, wait i will delete node_modules & will try it again. Or let me know any other solutions if you have